Setting first MenuItem color in ToolStripMenu (C#, WinForms)

I'm here to ask for help or suggestions. I'm creating a custom menu with a darker color. Almost everything is fine. The only thing I don't understand is why the first MenuItem has a default backcolor. The thing is the second one has the correct color. I don't know if I'm missing something, like, the first one gets the set color at launch or what.
I tried my code on a test project where the strip has a default red color and on Form_Load I change it. They both work perfectly. This is the code I'm using

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            menuStrip1.Renderer = new SkinRenderer(new MenuColorTable());
        }
        class MenuColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
        {
            public MenuColorTable()
            {
                base.UseSystemColors = false;
            }
            public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
            {
                get { return Color.FromArgb(12, 46, 73); }
            }
            public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
            {
                get { return Color.FromArgb(12, 46, 73); }
            }
            public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientBegin
            {
                get { return Color.FromArgb(6, 6, 6); }
            }
            public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientMiddle
            {
                get { return Color.FromArgb(6, 6, 6); }
            }
            public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientEnd
            {
                get { return Color.FromArgb(6, 6, 6); }
            }
            public override Color MenuBorder
            {
                get { return Color.FromArgb(127, 127, 127); }
            }
            public override Color ToolStripDropDownBackground
            {
                get { return Color.FromArgb(2, 2, 2); }
            }
            public override Color ImageMarginGradientBegin
            {
                get { return Color.FromArgb(10, 10, 10); }
            }
            public override Color ImageMarginGradientMiddle
            {
                get { return Color.FromArgb(10, 10, 10); }
            }
            public override Color ImageMarginGradientEnd
            {
                get { return Color.FromArgb(10, 10, 10); }
            }
            public override System.Drawing.Color MenuItemBorder
            {
                get { return Color.FromArgb(40, 158, 255); }
            }
            public override Color MenuItemSelected
            {
                get { return Color.FromArgb(12, 46, 73); ; }
            }
        }

        private class SkinRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
        {
            private SkinRenderer() : base() { }
            public SkinRenderer(MenuColorTable colorTable) : base(colorTable) => Console.WriteLine("test");
            protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e)
            {
                e.TextColor = Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220); ;
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Text, e.TextFont, e.TextRectangle, e.TextColor, e.TextFormat);
            }
            protected override void OnRenderArrow(ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs e)
            {
                ToolStripMenuItem item = e.Item as ToolStripMenuItem;
                if (item != null) { e.ArrowColor = Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220); }
                base.OnRenderArrow(e);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            menuStrip1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30);
        }
    }

}

I thought there was something in my code causing this behaviour but I'm not sure. I mean, it's true at launch the strip has a default color and during the load event I change that color, but why the first item stays default white and the second instead becomes the same color as the strip as it should? Any ideas? To be clear, there seems not to be anything in the code changing the menu's color except this. I tried to search for a property here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.professionalcolortable?view=windowsdesktop-8.0 but I couldn't find it. Did I miss it? It's true I could just force the specific control to change color on load, like thisItem.BackColor =, but why forcing something when IN THEORY it should already work correctly?

I can reproduce this if I set the fist menu item's BackColor to a value other than Control in the properties window.
Make sure the BackColor is set to Control in the properties window, otherwise this color will have precedence over the MenuColorTable of the renderer.

I'm also telling more: the color was in theory Control. No difference. EXCEPT. Although they were the same (literally) value, as it was chosen from the properties (Backcolor, Dropdown options, System, Control), my original project for some reason had it written in Bold style inside the properties, like it was some different value/color. I thought I could find something in the designer file but no. So instead I just right clicked on the Backcolor property and Reset the value. Now it works. Thank you!

I think the difference is whether an assignment was made in the *.Designer.cs or not.

There was nothing in the designer actually, that's what beats me...but in the end, whatever, I guess...

Not the designer in the IDE, I mean the file Form1.Designer.cs" in the method InitializeComponent`.

Yes, the designer code, I know, that's what i meant, I didn't find anything there, I don't know how or where that color was handled and changed but in the end the point is the issue is fixed :) so thank you again!
